# How to archive and restore a Hibernate entity with collections marked as "delete-orphan"

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

I am trying to create an archiving system where I can archive a complex Hibernate entity to file and later on (perhaps in a different instance of my web application) restore that instance as a new entity.

This is the entity I am currently trying to serialize:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "assessments")
public class Assessment implements Serializable, Comparable<Assessment>{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    [...]

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="assessment_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set<Module> modules = new TreeSet<Module>();

    [...]
}
```

I was previously using code to serialize to a file, then deserialize and store it, but since that was getting errors I tried the method below, which gets the same errors:

```
Assessment clone = (Assessment) SerializationHelper.clone(assessment);
clone.setId(null);
for(Module module : clone.getModules()) {
    module.setId(null);
}
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(clone);
```

When this code is executed, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : thisproject.domain.template.Assessment.modules; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : thisproject.domain.template.Assessment.modules
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:218)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:592)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at thisproject.repository.AssessmentDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dc4906d8.saveArchivedItem(<generated>)
    at thisproject.web.controller.SubmissionController.doSerial(SubmissionController.java:246)
    [...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Don't change the reference to a collection with delete-orphan enabled : thisproject.domain.template.Assessment.modules
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.prepareCollectionForUpdate(Collections.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:209)
    [...]
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get it to realise that I'm not changing the original assessment.

The assessment object actually has several collections of other serializable entities, however it always gets hung up on the modules. I'm not sure if that's just because it's the first one that Hibernate gets to (even though there is a near identical collection above it in the source), or if there is actually something wrong with the modules code.

I know this exception occurs when you set a collection rather than emptying and adding to the same collection, but I am not doing that. For reference, here is the setModules method:

```
public void setModules(Collection<Module> modules) {
    for(Module module : this.modules) {
        module.setAssessment(null);
    }
    this.modules.clear();
    for(Modules module : modules) {
        addModule(module);
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to correctly serialize and deserialize a Hibernate entity with collections marked as "delete-orphan"?

Comment: An interesting edge case serializing a hibernate entity to a file!  Edge cases are  one of the reasons I've moved away from orms.

Comment: Are you removing the Assessment and its entire entity graph from the database at the time you are serializing it to disk? That is, when you are attempting to deserialize and store to the database, is this being treated as an insert, or an update to existing records?

Comment: @Ben, for this specific example, I want to create a clone in the database, so it should be an insert. The original assessment should be untouched and stay in the database, while the new one should be inserted as a new assessment (and modules in this case).

Comment: Is modules the only relationship that has `delete-orphan=true` set? Just for fun have you tried first inserting the Assessment by itself (by clearing all itse related collections) and then loading it from the database and attempting to add the collections back to it? Just curious if that actually solves the issue.

Comment: @Ben, there are two other similar collections marked as `delete-orphan=true`. The modules is just the one that the error mentions.

The modules collection is actually already empty in the case that I am testing, but just for the sake of testing I specifically cleared it again. The error does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the `setModules` method, but you're not actually ever calling that and invoking `clear`.

My theory is that when you're serializing it, some internal state of the hibernate collection type used to hold `modules` is being serialized, and it is in a non-functional state after you deserialize and attempt to insert.

Perhaps you need to actually invoke the `clear` method on the collection before persisting, something like:

```java
Assessment clone = (Assessment) SerializationHelper.clone(assessment);
Set<Module> modules = clone.getModules();
for(Module m : modules) {
  m.setId(null);
}
clone.setModules(modules);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(clone);
```

Comment: I did some experimenting with this, calling the `setModules` method explicitly, and it doesn't seem to change. Even if it did, the problem would be that I don't want to change the modules; I just want to clone and persist them as well.

Comment: how deep does this object graph go? Do the Modules themselves have attributes marked as `orphanRemoval=true`? I'm still unclear if you're trying to insert new instances of every type in the entire object graph (new assessment referring to new module, referring to new ...) or if only the assessment is meant to be a new record in the database.

Comment: In this case, some of the attributes of Module do have `delete-orphan=true`. The given example is simplified for the purpose of the question, but my actual code sets all relevant IDs to null so that in theory the whole subgraph would be new inserts.

Comment: @RightOfZen, did you ever solve this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @brunobastosg Unfortunately I did not ever solve this; I moved on to another project.